Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "wieder" und "wieder einmal"?
Könnten Sie mir bitte erklären, was der Unterschied zwischen wieder und wieder einmal ist. Zum Beispiel:

Ich muss die Wohnung wieder putzen.
Ich muss die Wohnung wieder einmal putzen.


'wieder einmal' implies frequent recurrence, while plain 'wieder' doesn't.


Ich muss die Wohnung wieder einmal putzen.

Das sagt man, wenn man die Wohnung lange nicht geputzt hat, das Putzen überfällig ist.

Ich muss die Wohnung wieder putzen.
(Inhaltlich gleichbedeutend: Ich muss die Wohnung erneut putzen.)

Das sagt man normalerweise gar nicht. Damit man es dennoch sagt, muss ein Spezialfall eintreten, z. B. dieser:
In einer Wohnung wird eine Filmszene gedreht, wobei die Wohnung verschmutzt wird. Jedes Mal, bevor die Szene wiederholt werden kann, muss die Wohnung geputzt werden.
Doch selbst in diesem Fall wäre es natürlicher »Ich muss [schon] wieder die Wohnung putzen« zu sagen.
